# Can Halide be used with SOC Platforms?

Tags: halide

I'm trying to use Halide with Texas Instrument's TDA2x platform which is a SoC with DSP and other vision processors in it.

I basically want to run code generated by Halide in the DSP of TDA2x.
TDA2x supports TI's cl6x compiler.

How can I generate code from Halide to compile using cl6x compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, our only DSP backend is Hexagon. We don't have the ability to generate TDA2x code.

Halide compiles directly to machine code, not to C, so the cI6x compiler is not useful here. Halide *does* have a C-generating backend, but the performance of that code is often an order of magnitude worse than generating machine code directly, and it's not going to know about whatever intrinsics you need to program the TDA2x effectively, so I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. TI's cl6x can compile llvm code. 
I just want to know if the llvm code generated by Halide is optimized? or is it just like the C code halide generate?
Does the halide llvm code have architecture specific optimizations ?
Also if I want to run Halide code in TI's CC6x DSP, what's the best way to do that ? 
TI's llvm doesn't have a lot of intrinsics